# Link to a filtered view based on params

Tags: google-sheets

I have a `spreadsheet1` with the following columns:

```
name, country, value
```

In another `spreadsheet2` I'd like to have set of clickable links based on parameters:

```
param1, param2, link
```

where:

- `link` opens a new, filtered view of `spreadsheet1`, based on params from `spreadsheet2`
  something like:

  `spreadsheet1 where name=param1 and country=param2`

How can I achieve this in Google Spreadsheet? I know nothing about scripts yet.

Comment: This is an interesting use case. To better understand it, could you clarify a few things? (a) Should the new views should be editable, with edits reflected in the original spreadsheet? (b) Could multiple such links   be open at the same time? (c) Is it necessary to have spreadsheet1 and spreadsheet2 as separate spreadsheets, as opposed to sheets within the same spreadsheet?

Comment: Ideally, the new views would be editable too. But I'd be happy to have read only too. The same case with multiple links - does not really matter for now. I have some other data in the spreadsheet2 too, so ideally woudl be to have them in separate tab. But if this is not the easy option, I may move the data to the same spreadsheet.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to manage filtered views with a script; this is a [long-standing feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524). I think the most one can do is to programmatically create another sheet containing only the information that matches the criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, this can't be done as you wanted because of the lack of programmatic access to filtered views (until [this request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524) gets implemented).

So I wrote a script that does something along the lines that you wanted, but using the show/hide columns functionality. To simplify things, I am assuming that the data and the parameters are in different sheets of the same spreadsheet.

For example, suppose the first sheet of your spreadsheet is

```
+------+---------+-------+
| name | country | value |
+------+---------+-------+
| Alex | Canada  |   111 |
| Mary | Canada  |   222 |
| Alex | Brazil  |   333 |
| Mary | Brazil  |   444 |
| Mary | Canada  |   555 |
+------+---------+-------+
```

and the second sheet has

```
+------+---------+
| name | country |
+------+---------+
| Mary | Canada  |
| Alex | Brazil  |
| Mary | Brazil  |
+------+---------+
```

Instead of placing links in the second sheet, I opted for a simpler (for me) approach, a custom menu option:

[image: menu]

To use this:

1. Click on any cell in the row of the second sheet that has the parameters you want.
2. Choose "Filter" from the menu

You should see the first sheet filtered by the desired parameters:

```
+------+---------+-------+
| name | country | value |
+------+---------+-------+
| Mary | Canada  |   222 |
| Mary | Canada  |   555 |
+------+---------+-------+
```

To go back to seeing all rows, use the menu command "Show all".

Here is the script that does all of this: copy-paste it to `Tools->Script Editor` (erasing the placeholder there). After saving it, you will need to close and reopen the spreadsheet to have the custom menu option appear.

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Filter", functionName: "filter"}, {name: "Show all", functionName: "clear"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}

function filter() {
  clear(); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var name = values[0][0];
  var country = values[0][1];
  if (name&&country) {
    sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = range.getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0]!=name || values[i][1]!=country) {
        sheet.hideRow(range.getCell(i+1,1));
      }
    }
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet); 
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox('Parameters not found in the active row');
  }
}

function clear() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.showRows(1,lastRow);  
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance to bind this script to a click event on cell? Or automatically create a button in cell to run this script?

Comment: UPDATE: Request (linked above) has been implemented, so creating filters programmatically is now possible.